# boost::geometry::intersects doesn't work for different geometry types?

Tags: c++, boost-geometry

I am trying to use `boost::geometry::intersects` to check if a segment intersects a polygon. The following code works well:

```
#include <boost/geometry/algorithms/correct.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/algorithms/intersects.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/io/wkt/read.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  typedef bg::model::point<double, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> Point;
  bg::model::ring<Point> poly1, poly2;
  bg::model::segment<Point> s1, s2;

  bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((0.0 0.0, 1.0 1.0, 0.0 2.0, 2.0 1.0))", poly1);
  bg::correct(poly1);

  bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((1.5 0.0, 1.5 2.0, 3.0 1.0))", poly2);
  bg::correct(poly2);

  bg::read_wkt("SEGMENT(0.0 0.0,0.0 2.0)", s1);
  bg::read_wkt("SEGMENT(-1.0 1.0,2.0 1.0)", s2);

  std::cout << "Polygons intersect " << bg::intersects(poly1, poly2) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Segments intersect " << bg::intersects(s1, s2) << std::endl;
  //std::cout << "Polygon and segment intersect " << bg::intersects(poly1, s1) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

However, if I uncomment the line with `bg::intersects(poly1, s1)` I get the following compiling errors:

```
g++    -c -g -I/opt/local/include -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:8:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/correct.hpp:36:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/disjoint.hpp:33:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/detail/overlay/get_turns.hpp:56:
/opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/detail/sections/sectionalize.hpp:542:5: error: no matching function for call to 'assertion_failed'
    BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/local/include/boost/mpl/assert.hpp:434:48: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG'
#define BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG( c, msg, types_ ) \
                                               ^
/opt/local/include/boost/mpl/assert.hpp:428:9: note: expanded from macro '\
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG_IMPL'
        boost::mpl::assertion_failed<(c)>( BOOST_PP_CAT(mpl_assert_arg,counter)::assert_arg() ) \
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/local/include/boost/mpl/assert.hpp:59:58: note: expanded from macro '\
BOOST_MPL_AUX_ASSERT_CONSTANT'
#   define BOOST_MPL_AUX_ASSERT_CONSTANT(T, expr) enum { expr }
                                                         ^
/opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/detail/sections/sectionalize.hpp:661:5: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::geometry::dispatch::sectionalize<boost::geometry::segment_tag, boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, false, boost::geometry::sections<boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, 2>, 2, 10>' requested here
    sectionalizer_type::apply(geometry, sections, ring_id);
    ^
/opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/detail/overlay/get_turns.hpp:453:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::geometry::sectionalize<false, boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, boost::geometry::sections<boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, 2> >' requested here
        geometry::sectionalize<Reverse1>(geometry1, sec1, 0);
        ^
/opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/detail/overlay/get_turns.hpp:877:18: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::geometry::detail::get_turns::get_turns_generic<boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, boost::geometry::model::ring<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, true, true, std::vector, std::allocator>, false, false, std::__1::deque<boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_info<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_operation, boost::array<boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_operation, 2> >, std::__1::allocator<boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_info<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_operation, boost::array<boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_operation, 2> > > >, boost::geometry::detail::overlay::get_turn_info<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_info<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_operation, boost::array<boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_operation, 2> >, boost::geometry::detail::disjoint::assign_disjoint_policy>, boost::geometry::detail::disjoint::disjoint_interrupt_policy>::apply' requested here
        >::type::apply(
                 ^
/opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/disjoint.hpp:118:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::geometry::get_turns<false, false, boost::geometry::detail::disjoint::assign_disjoint_policy, boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, boost::geometry::model::ring<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, true, true, std::vector, std::allocator>, std::__1::deque<boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_info<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_operation, boost::array<boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_operation, 2> >, std::__1::allocator<boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_info<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_operation, boost::array<boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_operation, 2> > > >, boost::geometry::detail::disjoint::disjoint_interrupt_policy>' requested here
        geometry::get_turns
        ^
/opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/disjoint.hpp:159:54: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::geometry::detail::disjoint::disjoint_linear<boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, boost::geometry::model::ring<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, true, true, std::vector, std::allocator> >::apply' requested here
        if (! disjoint_linear<Geometry1, Geometry2>::apply(geometry1, geometry2))
                                                     ^
/opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/disjoint.hpp:261:16: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::geometry::detail::disjoint::general_areal<boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, boost::geometry::model::ring<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, true, true, std::vector, std::allocator> >::apply' requested here
            >::apply(g2, g1);
               ^
/opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/disjoint.hpp:344:54: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::geometry::dispatch::disjoint<boost::geometry::model::ring<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, true, true, std::vector, std::allocator>, boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, 2, boost::geometry::ring_tag, boost::geometry::segment_tag, true>::apply' requested here
    return dispatch::disjoint<Geometry1, Geometry2>::apply(geometry1, geometry2);
                                                     ^
/opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/intersects.hpp:99:14: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::geometry::disjoint<boost::geometry::model::ring<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, true, true, std::vector, std::allocator>, boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> > >' requested here
    return ! geometry::disjoint(geometry1, geometry2);
             ^
main.cpp:49:52: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::geometry::intersects<boost::geometry::model::ring<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, true, true, std::vector, std::allocator>, boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> > >' requested here
  std::cout << "Polygon and segment intersect " << bg::intersects(poly1,s1) << std::endl;
                                                   ^
/opt/local/include/boost/mpl/assert.hpp:82:5: note: candidate function [with C = false] not viable: no known conversion from 'boost::mpl::failed ************(boost::geometry::dispatch::sectionalize<boost::geometry::segment_tag, boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, false, boost::geometry::sections<boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, 2>, 2, 10>::NOT_OR_NOT_YET_IMPLEMENTED_FOR_THIS_GEOMETRY_TYPE::************)(types<boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> > >)' to 'typename assert<false>::type' (aka 'mpl_::assert<false>') for 1st argument
int assertion_failed( typename assert<C>::type );
    ^
In file included from main.cpp:8:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/correct.hpp:36:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/disjoint.hpp:33:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/detail/overlay/get_turns.hpp:35:
/opt/local/include/boost/geometry/views/detail/range_type.hpp:39:5: error: no matching function for call to 'assertion_failed'
    BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/local/include/boost/mpl/assert.hpp:434:48: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG'
#define BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG( c, msg, types_ ) \
                                               ^
/opt/local/include/boost/mpl/assert.hpp:428:9: note: expanded from macro '\
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG_IMPL'
        boost::mpl::assertion_failed<(c)>( BOOST_PP_CAT(mpl_assert_arg,counter)::assert_arg() ) \
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/local/include/boost/mpl/assert.hpp:59:58: note: expanded from macro '\
BOOST_MPL_AUX_ASSERT_CONSTANT'
#   define BOOST_MPL_AUX_ASSERT_CONSTANT(T, expr) enum { expr }
                                                         ^
/opt/local/include/boost/geometry/views/detail/range_type.hpp:94:32: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::geometry::dispatch::range_type<boost::geometry::segment_tag, boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> > >' requested here
    typedef typename dispatch::range_type
                               ^
/opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/detail/overlay/get_turns.hpp:104:22: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::geometry::detail::range_type<boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> > >' requested here
            typename range_type<Geometry1>::type const,
                     ^
/opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/detail/overlay/get_turns.hpp:408:20: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::geometry::detail::get_turns::get_turns_in_sections<boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, boost::geometry::model::ring<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, true, true, std::vector, std::allocator>, false, false, boost::geometry::section<boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, 2>, boost::geometry::section<boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, 2>, std::__1::deque<boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_info<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_operation, boost::array<boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_operation, 2> >, std::__1::allocator<boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_info<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_operation, boost::array<boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_operation, 2> > > >, boost::geometry::detail::overlay::get_turn_info<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_info<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_operation, boost::array<boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_operation, 2> >, boost::geometry::detail::disjoint::assign_disjoint_policy>, boost::geometry::detail::disjoint::disjoint_interrupt_policy>' requested here
            return get_turns_in_sections
                   ^
/opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/detail/partition.hpp:415:29: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::geometry::detail::get_turns::section_visitor<boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, boost::geometry::model::ring<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, true, true, std::vector, std::allocator>, false, false, std::__1::deque<boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_info<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_operation, boost::array<boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_operation, 2> >, std::__1::allocator<boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_info<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_operation, boost::array<boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_operation, 2> > > >, boost::geometry::detail::overlay::get_turn_info<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_info<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_operation, boost::array<boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_operation, 2> >, boost::geometry::detail::disjoint::assign_disjoint_policy>, boost::geometry::detail::disjoint::disjoint_interrupt_policy>::apply<boost::geometry::section<boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, 2> >' requested here
                    visitor.apply(*it1, *it2);
                            ^
/opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/detail/overlay/get_turns.hpp:464:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::geometry::partition<boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, boost::geometry::detail::get_turns::get_section_box, boost::geometry::detail::get_turns::ovelaps_section_box, boost::geometry::visit_no_policy>::apply<boost::geometry::sections<boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, 2>, boost::geometry::detail::get_turns::section_visitor<boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, boost::geometry::model::ring<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, true, true, std::vector, std::allocator>, false, false, std::__1::deque<boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_info<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_operation, boost::array<boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_operation, 2> >, std::__1::allocator<boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_info<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_operation, boost::array<boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_operation, 2> > > >, boost::geometry::detail::overlay::get_turn_info<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_info<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_operation, boost::array<boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_operation, 2> >, boost::geometry::detail::disjoint::assign_disjoint_policy>, boost::geometry::detail::disjoint::disjoint_interrupt_policy> >' requested here
        geometry::partition
        ^
/opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/detail/overlay/get_turns.hpp:877:18: note: (skipping 2 contexts in backtrace; use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
        >::type::apply(
                 ^
/opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/disjoint.hpp:159:54: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::geometry::detail::disjoint::disjoint_linear<boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, boost::geometry::model::ring<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, true, true, std::vector, std::allocator> >::apply' requested here
        if (! disjoint_linear<Geometry1, Geometry2>::apply(geometry1, geometry2))
                                                     ^
/opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/disjoint.hpp:261:16: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::geometry::detail::disjoint::general_areal<boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, boost::geometry::model::ring<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, true, true, std::vector, std::allocator> >::apply' requested here
            >::apply(g2, g1);
               ^
/opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/disjoint.hpp:344:54: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::geometry::dispatch::disjoint<boost::geometry::model::ring<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, true, true, std::vector, std::allocator>, boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, 2, boost::geometry::ring_tag, boost::geometry::segment_tag, true>::apply' requested here
    return dispatch::disjoint<Geometry1, Geometry2>::apply(geometry1, geometry2);
                                                     ^
/opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/intersects.hpp:99:14: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::geometry::disjoint<boost::geometry::model::ring<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, true, true, std::vector, std::allocator>, boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> > >' requested here
    return ! geometry::disjoint(geometry1, geometry2);
             ^
main.cpp:49:52: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::geometry::intersects<boost::geometry::model::ring<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, true, true, std::vector, std::allocator>, boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> > >' requested here
  std::cout << "Polygon and segment intersect " << bg::intersects(poly1,s1) << std::endl;
                                                   ^
/opt/local/include/boost/mpl/assert.hpp:82:5: note: candidate function [with C = false] not viable: no known conversion from 'boost::mpl::failed ************(boost::geometry::dispatch::range_type<boost::geometry::segment_tag, boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> > >::NOT_OR_NOT_YET_IMPLEMENTED_FOR_THIS_GEOMETRY_TYPE::************)(types<boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> > >)' to 'typename assert<false>::type' (aka 'mpl_::assert<false>') for 1st argument
int assertion_failed( typename assert<C>::type );
    ^
In file included from main.cpp:8:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/correct.hpp:23:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range.hpp:26:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/functions.hpp:18:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/begin.hpp:24:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/iterator.hpp:23:
/opt/local/include/boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp:60:26: error: no type named 'type' in 'boost::range_const_iterator<int>'
    typedef typename f_::type type;
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
/opt/local/include/boost/range/iterator.hpp:61:18: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::mpl::eval_if_c<true, boost::range_const_iterator<int>, boost::range_mutable_iterator<const int> >' requested here
            mpl::eval_if_c< is_const<C>::value,
                 ^
/opt/local/include/boost/geometry/views/identity_view.hpp:38:29: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::range_iterator<const int>' requested here
    typedef typename boost::range_iterator<Range const>::type const_iterator;
                            ^
/opt/local/include/boost/range/const_iterator.hpp:36:9: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::geometry::identity_view<const int>' requested here
        BOOST_RANGE_EXTRACT_OPTIONAL_TYPE( const_iterator )
        ^
/opt/local/include/boost/range/detail/extract_optional_type.hpp:45:82: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_RANGE_EXTRACT_OPTIONAL_TYPE'
    , BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME boost::range_detail::exists< BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME C::a_typedef >::type \
                                                                                 ^
/opt/local/include/boost/range/const_iterator.hpp:36:9: note: during template argument deduction for class template partial specialization 'extract_const_iterator<type-parameter-0-0, typename exists<typename type-parameter-0-0::const_iterator>::type>' [with C = boost::geometry::identity_view<const int>]
        BOOST_RANGE_EXTRACT_OPTIONAL_TYPE( const_iterator )
        ^
/opt/local/include/boost/range/detail/extract_optional_type.hpp:44:12: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_RANGE_EXTRACT_OPTIONAL_TYPE'
    struct extract_ ## a_typedef< C                                            \
           ^
<scratch space>:16:1: note: expanded from here
extract_const_iterator
^
/opt/local/include/boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp:60:22: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::range_const_iterator<boost::geometry::identity_view<const int> >' requested here
    typedef typename f_::type type;
                     ^
/opt/local/include/boost/range/iterator.hpp:61:18: note: (skipping 7 contexts in backtrace; use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
            mpl::eval_if_c< is_const<C>::value,
                 ^
/opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/disjoint.hpp:159:54: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::geometry::detail::disjoint::disjoint_linear<boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, boost::geometry::model::ring<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, true, true, std::vector, std::allocator> >::apply' requested here
        if (! disjoint_linear<Geometry1, Geometry2>::apply(geometry1, geometry2))
                                                     ^
/opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/disjoint.hpp:261:16: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::geometry::detail::disjoint::general_areal<boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, boost::geometry::model::ring<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, true, true, std::vector, std::allocator> >::apply' requested here
            >::apply(g2, g1);
               ^
/opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/disjoint.hpp:344:54: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::geometry::dispatch::disjoint<boost::geometry::model::ring<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, true, true, std::vector, std::allocator>, boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >, 2, boost::geometry::ring_tag, boost::geometry::segment_tag, true>::apply' requested here
    return dispatch::disjoint<Geometry1, Geometry2>::apply(geometry1, geometry2);
                                                     ^
/opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/intersects.hpp:99:14: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::geometry::disjoint<boost::geometry::model::ring<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, true, true, std::vector, std::allocator>, boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> > >' requested here
    return ! geometry::disjoint(geometry1, geometry2);
             ^
main.cpp:49:52: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::geometry::intersects<boost::geometry::model::ring<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, true, true, std::vector, std::allocator>, boost::geometry::model::segment<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> > >' requested here
  std::cout << "Polygon and segment intersect " << bg::intersects(poly1,s1) << std::endl;
                                                   ^
In file included from main.cpp:8:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/correct.hpp:23:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range.hpp:26:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/functions.hpp:18:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/begin.hpp:24:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/iterator.hpp:23:
/opt/local/include/boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp:60:26: error: no type named 'type' in 'boost::range_const_iterator<boost::geometry::identity_view<const int> >'
    typedef typename f_::type type;
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
/opt/local/include/boost/range/iterator.hpp:61:18: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::mpl::eval_if_c<true, boost::range_const_iterator<boost::geometry::identity_view<const int> >, boost::range_mutable_iterator<const boost::geometry::identity_view<const int> > >' requested here
            mpl::eval_if_c< is_const<C>::value,
                 ^
/opt/local/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/detail/overlay/get_turns.hpp:124:29: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::range_iterator<const boost::geometry::identity_view<const int> >' requested here
    typedef typename boost::range_iterator
                            ^
...

8 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

Is that a bug or am I forgetting something?

Comment: Does `bg::intersects(s1, poly1)` also fail? Going by http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/intersects/intersects_2_two_geometries.html your code looks valid, so I'm wondering if Boost.Geometry makes some assumptions for efficiency under the hood that are violated by your usage of a geometry model with area and a geometry model without area (I know that with a [non-Boost] geometry library I'd used in the past, I had to use extremely narrow triangles rather than lines for intersection checks, so the same may be the case here).

Comment: (By the way, is there a reason you didn't load `s2` with endpoints or did you just leave that out? Your second intersection check seems odd without that.)

Comment: @JAB, `bg::intersects(s1, poly1)` also fails. Your comment on geometries with/without areas sounds reasonable. However I just checked if `bg::intersects` works for a linestring and a segment, and it doesn't. Looks like they require the geometries to be the same, or maybe they didn't implement it for all possible pairs...

Comment: @JAB, thanks for pointing out, I fixed the code (I, of course, did load `s2` when testing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your thought that "maybe they didn't implement it for all possible pairs" is indeed the issue. [`boost::geometry::intersects`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/geometry/algorithms/intersects.hpp) calls [`boost::geometry::disjoint`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/geometry/algorithms/disjoint.hpp) under the hood, and there are indeed template specializations for testing disjoint with different model types, including `Segment` + `Box` and `Linestring` + `Box`, but there does not appear to be one for `Segment` + `Ring` (though there is also one for `Linestring` + `Segment`, and though the templates are a bit tricky to walk through there does appear to be a middleman template that will switch the order of type parameters around to match, which means if you're having an issue with those two there might be some deeper issue).

Comment: I tried `bg::intersects` for `Linestring` + `Segment` in both orders and I get the same errors. Probably `boost::geomery::disjoint` is not the only thing that it calls under the hood. Anyway, thanks for your reply! I guess, there's not much can be done here.

Comment: @shalabuda That's how these things go sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit old but the other answer wasn't great. My solution is to convert them both to line strings and then find out if they intersect (if you think about it the result should be the same, but it won't work for intersection)

```
#include <boost/geometry/algorithms/correct.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/algorithms/intersects.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/io/wkt/read.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  typedef bg::model::point<double, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> Point;
  typedef bg::model::linestring<Point> linestring;
  bg::model::ring<Point> poly1, poly2;
  bg::model::segment<Point> s1, s2; 

  bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((0.0 0.0, 1.0 1.0, 0.0 2.0, 2.0 1.0))", poly1);
  bg::correct(poly1);

  bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((1.5 0.0, 1.5 2.0, 3.0 1.0))", poly2);
  bg::correct(poly2);

  bg::read_wkt("SEGMENT(0.0 0.0,0.0 2.0)", s1);
  bg::read_wkt("SEGMENT(-1.0 1.0,2.0 1.0)", s2);

  std::cout << "Polygons intersect " << bg::intersects(poly1, poly2) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Segments intersect " << bg::intersects(s1, s2) << std::endl;
  std::vector<Point> v{s1.first,s1.second};
  std::cout << "Polygon and segment intersect " << bg::intersects(linestring(poly1.begin(),poly1.end()), linestring(v.begin(),v.end())) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I ended up doing. Boost geometry has potential, but it is not ready to be used in a serious project. Too many of those workarounds...

Comment: @shalabuda there is another library called goes, but I though most of the code was ugly and unusable. It does have more functionality though.